# Redimensionar bitmap gerado em c# para melhor visualização

Tags: c#, código-de-barras

Estou com um programa para gerar código de barras do tipo *Interleaved 2 of 5*. Peguei o código deste [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19948/Bar-Code-Drawing) mas como foi postado em 2007 não consegui resposta para a minha pergunta. O programa gera um *bitmap* com o código de barras e insiro-o em uma `picture-box`. Entretanto este *bitmap* está muito pequeno impossibilitando a leitura do código por um leitor. Já tentei redimensionar o *bitmap* na hora da sua criação mas ele "sempre" ocupa o mesmo espaço. A imagem abaixo é como ele mostra o código de barras. O código base foram os números "1234567890" e os dois `label` abaixo do botão foram para teste o primeiro é o *width* e o segundo é o *height* do *bitmap* :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código completo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string CalcCheckSum(string CheckNum)
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        int checkval = 0;
        j = 3;
        i = CheckNum.Length - 1;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            checkval += Convert.ToInt32(CheckNum.Substring(i, 1)) * j;
            j = j ^ 2;
            i -= 1;
        }
        checkval = (10 - (checkval % 10)) % 10;
        return checkval.ToString();
    }

    public string Get2of5Pattern(string letter)
    {
        string tmpPattern = "";
        switch (letter)
        {
            case "0":
                tmpPattern = "NNWWN";
                break;
            case "1":
                tmpPattern = "WNNNW";
                break;
            case "2":
                tmpPattern = "NWNNW";
                break;
            case "3":
                tmpPattern = "WWNNN";
                break;
            case "4":
                tmpPattern = "NNWNW";
                break;
            case "5":
                tmpPattern = "WNWNN";
                break;
            case "6":
                tmpPattern = "NWWNN";
                break;
            case "7":
                tmpPattern = "NNNWW";
                break;
            case "8":
                tmpPattern = "WNNWN";
                break;
            case "9":
                tmpPattern = "NWNWN";
                break;
        }
        return tmpPattern;
    }

    public Bitmap Print2of5Interleaved()
    {
        string Content = "1234567890";
        string CheckSum = CalcCheckSum(Content);
        string startcode = "1010";
        string stopcode = "1101";
        int startX = 0;
        int startY = 0;
        int endY = startY + 40;
        int curX;
        int sectionIndex = 0;
        int pairIndex = 0;
        int barIndex = 0;
        int spaceIndex = 0;

        Graphics g;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(10000, 8000);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        curX = startX;
        //Content = Content + CheckSum;
        if ((Content.Length % 2) != 0)
        {
            //odd number, fill in a leading zero
            Content = "0" + Content;
        }
        //draw the start marker
        foreach (char digit in startcode)
        {
            if (digit == '1')
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, curX, startY, curX, endY);
                curX += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                curX += 1;
            }
        }
        //draw the content
        for (int i = 0; i < Content.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string pair = Content.Substring(i, 2);
            string barPattern = Get2of5Pattern(pair.Substring(0, 1));
            string spacePattern = Get2of5Pattern(pair.Substring(1, 1));
            barIndex = 0;
            spaceIndex = 0;
            sectionIndex = 0;
            while (sectionIndex < 10)
            {
                if ((sectionIndex % 2) == 0)
                {
                    //bar 0,2,4,6,8 positions
                    pairIndex = 0;
                    if (barPattern.Substring(barIndex, 1) == "W")
                    {
                        //draw wide bar
                        while (pairIndex < 2)
                        {
                            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, curX + pairIndex, startY, curX + pairIndex, endY);
                            pairIndex++;
                        }
                        curX = curX + 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //draw narrow bar
                        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, curX + pairIndex, startY, curX + pairIndex, endY);
                        curX = curX + 1;
                    }
                    barIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //space 1,3,5,7,8 positions
                    if (spacePattern.Substring(spaceIndex, 1) == "W")
                    {
                        //simulate drawing a wide white space
                        curX = curX + 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //simulate drawing a narrow white space
                        curX = curX + 1;
                    }
                    spaceIndex++;
                }
                sectionIndex += 1;
            }
        }
        //draw the stop marker
       foreach (char digit in stopcode)
        {
            if (digit == '1')
            {
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, curX, startY, curX, endY);
                curX += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                curX += 1;
            }
        }
        return bmp;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Print2of5Interleaved();
        label1.Text = Print2of5Interleaved().Width.ToString();
        label2.Text = Print2of5Interleaved().Height.ToString();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}}
```

E nesta outra imagem é como está a propriedade de criação do *Bitmap*, eu coloquei para ser criado do zero como `new Bitmap(width,height)` com os valores mostrados na imagem anterior nos `labels`. Mas quando passo o mouse por cima mostra essa definição que o *bitmap* está sendo criado com as dimensões de uma imagem existente `new Bitmap(Image original, Size newSize)`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Preciso de uma ajuda urgente para conseguir aumentar esse bitmap e fazer o leitor conseguir ler para daí verificar se o programa está correto mesmo, já aviso sou iniciante em programação ainda mais em C#!! Obrigada desde já!

Comment: @ctgPi funcionou, obrigada! Deixe como resposta para eu poder marcar como certa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar algo tipo

```
g.ScaleTransform(2.0f, 2.0f)
```

A chamada [`ScaleTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zhc2xxtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) faz todos os comandos gráficos que a seguem serem desenhados com o aumento de tamanho especificado.